# Retrieve curl data with client headers/IP

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

```
$url_in = 'http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=3145131&id=159485516&hash=d821df23b7dc0b54&hd=1';  
function curl($url, $cookie = false, $post = false, $header = false, $follow_location = false)  
{ 
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $follow_location); 
if ($cookie) { 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie); 
} 
if ($post) { 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
} 
$response = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
return $response; 
} 

$vk_video = curl($url_in); 
preg_match('|host=(.*)&|Uis', $vk_video, $link1); 
preg_match('|uid=(.*)&|Uis', $vk_video, $link2); 
preg_match('|vtag=(.*)&|Uis', $vk_video, $link3); 
$link= $link1['1'].'u'.$link2['1'].'/video/'.$link3['1'].'.360.mp4';
echo $link;
```

the problem is that `vtag=` is different for every ip client so how can i retrieve the `vtag` with client ip?

Comment: If you want to distinguish between different users, use **`sessions`**.

Comment: The question is unclear, please try to explain in other words by editing the question above. _If_ the vtag value is different (your words) and you extract the value by using a regex, then what is the problem?

Comment: @arkascha if you run the code you will see that on your server the `vtag` is different from the direct access with the browser [link](http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=3145131&id=159485516&hash=d821df23b7dc0b54&hd=1)

Comment: @Cthulhu how can i do with the sessions?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were saying earlier. Now it seems like you want to make it look like the client is fetching the page. Curl won't let your spoof IP like that.

Comment: @Cthulhu do you have some idea on how could i retrieve data from [link](http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=3145131&id=159485516&hash=d821df23b7dc0b54&hd=1) like the client is fetching the page?

Comment: @IlieBoldijar PHP is at your server. The right tool for that would be JavaScript, which executes at the client.

Comment: @Cthulhu how can i do this, the javascript will be k but i have no idea how to work it out give me some ideas thanks

Comment: @IlieBoldijar You could start at fetching URLs using [**AJAX**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX).

Comment: @Cthulhu could you please create me an example? Thanks

Comment: Google it! There are enough examples floating around as it is. I think you should make an effort at understanding how it works. x-(

Comment: @Cthulhu i'm new you could just throw me an example thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @IlieBoldijar This should get you started --> http://techrageo.us/2007/08/03/jquery-makes-ajax-easy-part-1/