# Vkontakte vtag issues

Tags: php, curl, vk

[Retrieve curl data with client headers/IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362874/retrieve-curl-data-with-client-headers-ip)

I have same problem. I dont understand but not in localhost. everything fine on my localhost. just dont get correct video url on my website. i guess there is some server ip issues.

```
$url_in = 'http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=3145131&id=159485516&hash=d821df23b7dc0b54&hd=1';  
function curl($url, $cookie = false, $post = false, $header = false, $follow_location = false)  
{ 
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $follow_location); 
if ($cookie) { 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie); 
} 
if ($post) { 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
} 
$response = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
return $response; 
} 

$vk_video = curl($url_in); 
preg_match('|host=(.*)&|Uis', $vk_video, $link1); 
preg_match('|uid=(.*)&|Uis', $vk_video, $link2); 
preg_match('|vtag=(.*)&|Uis', $vk_video, $link3); 
$link= $link1['1'].'u'.$link2['1'].'/video/'.$link3['1'].'.360.mp4';
echo $link;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function geturl($url, $quality)
{
$vkurl = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('/&amp;url'.$quality.'=(.*?)&amp;/mis', $vkurl, $C);
return $C[1];
}

echo geturl('http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=3145131&id=159485516&hash=d821df23b7dc0b54&hd=1', '240'); //gives 240p video

echo geturl('http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=3145131&id=159485516&hash=d821df23b7dc0b54&hd=1', '360'); //gives 360p video

echo geturl('http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=3145131&id=159485516&hash=d821df23b7dc0b54&hd=1', '480'); //gives 480p video

echo geturl('http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=3145131&id=159485516&hash=d821df23b7dc0b54&hd=1', '720'); //gives 720p video
```

NOTE: YOU CAN'T GENERATE VIDEO URLS FOR THE CLIENT. YOU CAN ONLY GENERATE URLS FOR YOUR SERVER THEN YOU CAN STREAM VIDEOS FROM YOUR SERVER